# How to correctly export kubernetes resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I've created several resources using [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) Ansible module. Now I'd like to export the resources into Kubernetes manifests (so I don't need to use Ansible anymore). I've started by exporting a Service:

```
$ kubectl get svc myservice -o yaml --export > myservice.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f myservice.yaml 
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
service/myservice configured
```

Why do I get the the warning? And why there's `service/myservice configured` and not `service/myservice unchanged`? Is there a better way to export resources?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing right, don't worry about the *warning*.

If you want to get rid of it, you have to delete all the `generation`, `selfLink` and so on keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it right.
Let me show you small trick:

```
kubectl get svc myservice -o yaml --export | sed -e '/status:/d' -e '/creationTimestamp:/d' -e '/selfLink: [a-z0-9A-Z/]\+/d' -e '/resourceVersion: "[0-9]\+"/d' -e '/phase:/d' -e '/uid: [a-z0-9-]\+/d' > myservice.yaml
```

Will generate proper yaml file without `status, creationTimestamp, selfLink, resourceVersion, phase and uid`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because you're using `kubectl apply` on a resource that you previously created with `kubectl create`. If you create the initial Service with `kubectl apply`, you shouldn't get the warning.

The `configured` instead of `unchanged` might be because of some metadata or generated data that is also included in the output of `kubectl get svc myservice -o yaml --export`.